# How to make a flat icon button in angular material 2?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want an icon button the same as the one on the [angular material documentation site](https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples).

You can check the *view source* and *plunker* button in the below image. I don't know if there is any directive for it. In the documentation, they have shown icons with `md-fab` and `md-mini-fab` attributes.

I want an icon button the same as the `View source code` and `Plunker` button of the below image.

[image: Angular Material Docs > Button > Examples]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `md-icon-button` attribute on your `button` element to get an icon button:

```html
<button md-icon-button mdTooltip="Check me">
    <md-icon>check</md-icon>
</button>
```

**NOTE:** If you use [Material Icons by Google](https://material.io/icons), make sure you import the stylesheet in your `index.html` or in your `styles.css` as material2 will not supply it by default. *(You may alternatively use other icons such as [SVG icons](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/icon/icon.md#svg-icons) or [CSS](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/icon/icon.md#font-icons-with-css))*

Add the following code for importing the Material Icons stylesheet to your `index.html` (as stated above):

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or via CSS (in `styles.css`):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
```

**More information**:

- [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/CyNmjbjWIzWymg4fmdig?p=preview)
- [Markdown doc for `button` and its attributes](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/button/button.md)
- [Material Icons - A guide on how to use the Material Icons library](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons)